# how to get audio files from folder using their path from database in asp.net .?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get audio files from folder using their path from database and also write code for file downloading please give reply to me.

this is my handler code. If i use this code I am play only one audio file if upload another file it is also same ply same thing as a before upload file music - I mean same music was played at a time

```
public class audiofiles : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int newsid = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["newsid"]);
        byte[] bytes;
        string contentType;
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString;
        string name;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_userpost_newsaudios where newsid=@newsid";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsid", newsid);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["audiodata"];
                contentType = sdr["contenttype"].ToString();
                name = sdr["audioname"].ToString();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
        context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

my design code:-

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='../players/dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=audiofiles.ashx?newsid=<%# Eval("newsid") %>'
            width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="movie" value='../players/dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=audiofiles.ashx?newsid=<%# Eval("newsid") %>'/>
        </object>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="newsid" Text = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/user/audiofiles.ashx?newsid={0}" HeaderText="Download" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: There seems not wrong with this code, you need to explain more clearly where the problem is and what you do in the browser to start this code.

Comment: it is working but , i want play multiple files using grid view or datalist problem is only one file is worked successfully other file also played same music.

Comment: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='../players/dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=audiofiles.ashx?newsid=<%# Eval("newsid") %>' width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                        <param name="movie" value='../players/dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=audiofiles.ashx?newsid=<%# Eval("newsid") %>'/>
                    </object>
                </ItemTemplate>  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="newsid" Text = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/user/audiofiles.ashx?newsid={0}" HeaderText="Download" />

Comment: @EswarRao - please don't write code in comments - the formatting doesn't work there. You can edit your question to add these further details.

Comment: sorry ...i am already that is write in above design code..plz check it..